# How do I assign one level deeper in my list?

Tags: r

I'd like to assign objects into a list three levels down and it's giving me a hard time with the subscripts.

This is my code

```
    dataset <- iris
    nums <- data.frame(vars = c("Sepal.Length", "Petal.Width"))
    l <- list()
    i <- 1
    
    l[["nums"]][["visits_d7"]][["tabSuspectedOutliers"]] <-
        paste0(round(
        sort(as_vector(dataset[
        !is.na(as_vector(dataset[as.character(nums$vars[i])])),
      ][
        scores(as_vector(dataset[as.character(nums$vars[i])])[
          !is.na(as_vector(dataset[as.character(nums$vars[i])]))], 
             type = "iqr",
             lim = 1.5),
        as.character(nums$vars[i])
      ]))), 
        collapse = ", ")
  
    l[["nums"]][[as.character(nums$vars[i])]][["ggHistogram"]] <-
      dataset %>% 
        select(var = nums$vars[i]) %>% 
        ggplot(aes(var)) +
        geom_histogram()
```

This gives me the error: Error in `*tmp*`[[as.character(nums$vars[i])]] : subscript out of bounds

Comment: can you define the `scores` function?

Comment: scores comes from the package `outliers`

Comment: can you define `as_vector`? Is it a typo for `as.vector`? Or from a non-base package?

Comment: It's from dplyr